# How to remove consecutive bad data points in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sensors

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dummy_Var": [1]*12, 
                   "B": [6, 143.3, 143.3, 143.3, 3, 4, 93.9, 93.9, 93.9, 2, 2, 7],
                   "C": [4.1, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 4.3, 2.5, 7.8, 7.8, 2, 7, 7, 7]})


    B       C       Dummy_Var
0   6.0     4.1     1
1   143.3   23.2    1
2   143.3   23.2    1
3   143.3   23.2    1
4   3.0     4.3     1
5   4.0     2.5     1
6   93.9    7.8     1
7   93.9    7.8     1
8   93.9    2.0     1
9   2.0     7.0     1
10  2.0     7.0     1
11  7.0     7.0     1
```

Whenever the same numbers show up consecutively three times or more in a row, that data should be replaced with `NAN`. So the result should be:

```
    B       C       Dummy_Var
0   6.0     4.1     1
1   NaN     NaN     1
2   NaN     NaN     1
3   NaN     NaN     1
4   3.0     4.3     1
5   4.0     2.5     1
6   NaN     7.8     1
7   NaN     7.8     1
8   NaN     2.0     1
9   2.0     NaN     1
10  2.0     NaN     1
11  7.0     NaN     1
```

I have written a function that does that:

```
def non_sense_remover(df, examined_columns, allowed_repeating):
    def count_each_group(grp, column):
        grp['Count'] = grp[column].count()
        return grp
    for col in examined_columns:
        sel = df.groupby((df[col] != df[col].shift(1)).cumsum()).apply(count_each_group, column=col)["Count"] > allowed_repeating
        df.loc[sel, col] = np.nan

    return df

df = non_sense_remover(df, ["B", "C"], 2)
```

However, my real dataframe has 2M rows and 18 columns! It is very very slow to run this function on 2M rows. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We using `groupby` + `mask`

```
m=df[['B','C']]
df[['B','C']]=m.mask(m.apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count'))>2)
df
Out[1245]: 
      B    C  Dummy_Var
0   6.0  4.1          1
1   NaN  NaN          1
2   NaN  NaN          1
3   NaN  NaN          1
4   3.0  4.3          1
5   4.0  2.5          1
6   NaN  7.8          1
7   NaN  7.8          1
8   NaN  2.0          1
9   2.0  NaN          1
10  2.0  NaN          1
11  7.0  NaN          1
```

Comment: This approach took 7 seconds to finish the task on my 2M row dataframe with 18 columns. It would be great if you can elaborate in your answer why my initial function was so slow.

Comment: @ahoosh for loop is time costing function , if you are working with pandas try not using for loop here

Answer (score 3):

Constructing a boolean mask in this situation will be far more efficient than a solution based on `apply()`, particularly for large datasets. Here is an approach:

```
cols = df[['B', 'C']]
mask = (cols.shift(-1) == cols) & (cols.shift(1) == cols)

df[mask | mask.shift(1).fillna(False) | mask.shift(-1).fillna(False)] = np.nan
```

---

Edit:

For a more general approach, replacing sequences of length `N` with `NaN`, you could do something like this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_, and_

def replace_sequential_duplicates_with_nan(df, N):
    mask = reduce(and_, [cols.shift(i) == cols.shift(i + 1)
                         for i in range(N - 1)])
    full_mask = reduce(or_, [mask.shift(-i).fillna(False)
                             for i in range(N)])
    df[full_mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: That is a speedy solution. What if the accepted limit is 9? i.e. 9 consecutive points in a row is ok, but we assign `NaN` to them as soon as there are 10 or more. Can we generalize this approach?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This approach took 22 seconds to finish the task on my 2M row dataframe with 18 columns. It is very elegant and I learned a ton from it.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392758/how-can-i-write-data-processing-code-using-pandas-that-gives-me-at-least-as-high), it appears that using apply/transform (in your case, apply) is causing the biggest bottleneck here. The link I referenced goes into much more detail about why this is and how to solve it